# Reducing distance between Parent and Child level

Tags: forest

I'm trying to reduce the distance between levels AA and A in the picture, I tried to use `l sep` but it didn't work.[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  basic/.style = {draw, thin, drop shadow, font=\sffamily},
  upper style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, edge+={-Stealth, thin}, fill=gray!10, text width=9em},
  lower style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=0pt, edge+={-, line width=.4pt}, fill=black!10, text width=9em},
  where level<=2{%     upper style,
    edge path'={
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)
    },text width=7em
  }{%
    lower style,
  },
  where level<=1{%
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    if={isodd(n_children())}{%
      calign=child edge,
      calign primary child/.process={
        O+nw+n{n children}{(#1+1)/2}
      },
    }{%
      calign=edge midpoint,
    },
  }{
    folder,
    grow'=0,
  },  [Survey Structure,text width=8em,
    [Part I: Introduction,, folder, grow'=0, for children={lower style},text width=10em, 
      [AA
      , folder, grow'=0, for children={upper style},
       [A]
       [B]
       [C]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`l sep` cannot work here.  In this tree, the folders are set to grow to the east (`grow'=0`), so any settings regarding the `l` dimension can only affect the `x` dimension.

The gap between `AA` and `A` in the OP's code arises due to overapplication of key `folder`. This key does not merely set some value (as `l sep` does, for example).  It is a complex style, which, among other things, pushes the children of the node around to yield the illusion of a folder.  Given `grow'=0`, the children start their life east of the folder node; it is key `folder` which "manually" moves them to the position below the folder node. This is why applying `folder` more than once can lead to unexpected behaviour.

In the code below, I have cleaned-up the preamble and the tree so that `folder` is executed only once (for all nodes but the root), while setting the appropriate style for a node with respect to its level. This is achieved within `for children` just below comment `(2)`.

The code below comment `(1)` deals with the transition between a non-folder and a folder node, which is notoriously problematic.  Automatic c-alignment (the position of a node with respect to its children) does not work here, because it relies on the `anchor` setting, which is "hijacked" by style `folder`. The c-alignment must thus be performed manually. Below, the transition occurs between the root node and its children, and I have centered the root directly above the selected (`calign child`) child.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  basic/.style = {draw, thin, drop shadow, font=\sffamily},
  upper style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, edge+={-Stealth, thin}, fill=gray!10, text width=9em},
  lower style/.style = {basic, rounded corners=0pt, edge+={-, line width=.4pt}, fill=black!10, text width=9em},
  % (1) manual c-alignment of the root node (change "calign child" to align to a non-first child)
  calign=child, calign child=1,
  after packing node={
    tempdima={max_x("!n={calign_primary_child())}")/2},
    for children={s-/.register=tempdima},
  },
  % (2) Apply "folder", "grow", and the level-specific style to the non-root nodes.
  for children={
    % level 1
    grow'=0, folder,
    for children={
      % level 2
      lower style,
      grow'=0, folder,
      for descendants={
        % level > 2
        upper style,
        grow'=0, folder, 
      },
    },
  },
  [Survey Structure, text width=8em,
    [Part I: Introduction, text width=10em, 
      [AA
       [A]
       [B]
       [C]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```